# Multiple Buttons in GWT Popup Window

Tags: gwt

I am trying to set up a webpage with multiple buttons that go to multiple popups. The code is as such;

```
final PopupPanel jal2 = new PopupPanel();
        jal2.show();
        organizeFolders.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
                {
                    Window.alert("Red Button clicked!");
                }
        })
        ;
        organizeIntoFolders.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                Window.alert("Red Button clicked!");
            }
        })
        ;
        organizeFiles.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {

                Button filesNames= new Button("Files according to names");
                Button fileTypes = new Button("Files according to their file types");
                Button fileAuthors = new Button("Files according to their authors");
                Button fileAlbums = new Button("Files according to their albums");
                filesNames.setStyleName("filesNames");
                filesNames.setSize("0.5px", "0.5px");
                fileTypes.setStyleName("fileTypes");
                fileTypes.setWidth("5px");
                fileTypes.setHeight("5px");
                fileAuthors.setStyleName("fileAuthors");
                fileAuthors.setWidth("5px");
                fileAuthors.setHeight("5px");
                fileAlbums.setStyleName("fileAlbums");
                fileAlbums.setWidth("5px");
                fileAlbums.setHeight("5px");
                jal2.addStyleName("popup");
                jal2.setSize("400px", "400px");

                jal2.add(filesNames.asWidget());
                jal2.add(fileTypes.asWidget());
                jal2.add(fileAuthors.asWidget());
                jal2.center();
                jal2.show();
                jal2.setVisible(true);
                jal2.add(fileAlbums.asWidget());

            }
        })
        ;
```

This code only opens up "files according to names" as a PopUp sized button:
http://s558.photobucket.com/user/magpiejay/media/button_zpskgbfgwtd.jpg.html

What I'm intending to do instead is:

- Have buttons that are properly sized.
- See all buttons, not just one widget that is the first added.
- And, if possible, find a way to properly center the Popup, as the current .center() method results in [this](http://s558.photobucket.com/user/magpiejay/media/button2_zpsvgrmqikc.jpg.html)

Answer (score 0):

**-Have buttons that are properly sized:**
Instead of setting the Buttons height and width with `setHeight("5px")` you could set the size in your CSS Style that you are setting with `.setStyleName("fileAuthors");`. Just add `width: 50px;` `and height:20px;` to your `fileAuthors class`.
If you dont add any size, the Buttons will have a size according to the text that you set on them.

**-See all buttons, not just one widget that is the first added:**
`PopupPanel` extends the `SimplePanel` and allows only one Widget to be added.
Instead of adding all Buttons directly to the `PopupPanel` first add a container and then add all Buttons this container.  If you do it as shown in the example, also the center method should work. Also you dont have to set it visible and neither call `show()` since all this is done in the `center()` method.(Maybe read the Javadoc)

Example:

```
organizeFiles.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                        // create a container
                        FlowPanel container = new FlowPanel();
                        Button filesNames = new Button("Files according to names");
                        Button fileTypes = new Button("Files according to their file types");
                        Button fileAuthors = new Button("Files according to their authors");
                        Button fileAlbums = new Button("Files according to their albums");
                        filesNames.setStyleName("filesNames");
                        filesNames.setSize("50px", "20px");
                        fileTypes.setStyleName("fileTypes");
                        fileTypes.setSize("50px", "20px");
                        fileAuthors.setStyleName("fileAuthors");
                        fileAuthors.setSize("50px", "20px");
                        fileAlbums.setStyleName("fileAlbums");
                        fileAlbums.setSize("50px", "20px");

                        jal2.addStyleName("popup");
                        jal2.setSize("400px", "400px");

                        container.add(filesNames);
                        container.add(fileTypes);
                        container.add(fileAuthors);
                        container.add(fileAlbums);
                        //set only the widget into the popuppanel
                        jal2.setWidget(container);
                        jal2.center();

            }
        })
        ;
```

Comment: This doesn't provide a proper panel, just floating buttons.

Comment: it looks like you are overriding the popup style somewhere. try to get it working without setting any of your styles but using the standard ones. when this works try to add your styles again

Comment: No, styles on Popup do not change much. What I'm trying to have is to keep the popup panel in a window.

Comment: Alright, when I add all onClick on all buttons, I see none of them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. It was happening because I did not add different style names to all popups and added those style names to CSS.
http://s558.photobucket.com/user/magpiejay/media/Balksz4_zpsestll7fs.jpg.html